# Yii dropDownList - where to do logic for selected item

Tags: php, yii, drop-down-menu, filter, selected

I'm trying to capture the value selected from a dropDownList from a CActiveForm and then do some logic on it after submit... to then run a query. Based on this query i would then update the gridview. This form doesn't have any attributes in a table that relate to it but its more so I can create a filter for my GridView after some logic.

Where would i perform this logic? I'm new to php, yii, and javascript so I'd appreciate at least pointing me to the right direction. I've tried to look at yii documentation and books but haven't found what i need. i think I'm missing something critical from php and web dev to be stuck on something so trivial as a drop down.

This is my view for admin.php which then calls the advanced_search.php form by renderPartial

```
    <?php
/* @var $this UserController */
/* @var $model User */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Manage Users',
);

/*$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List User', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create User', 'url'=>array('create')),
);
*/
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.asearch-button').click(function(){
    $('.asearch-form').toggle();
    $('.bsearch-form').toggle();
    return false;
});

$('.bsearch-button').click(function(){
    $('.bsearch-form').toggle();
    $('.asearch-form').toggle();
    return false;
});

$('.bsearch-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#user-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});

$('.asearch-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#user-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
}); 
");
?>

<h2>Manage Users</h2>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Basic Search','#',array('class'=>'bsearch-button')); ?>
<br/>

<!-- basic search-form -->
<div class="bsearch-form" style="display:">
    <?php $this->renderPartial('search',array('model'=>$model)); ?>
</div>


<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'asearch-button')); ?>

<!-- advanced search-form -->
<div class="asearch-form" style="display:none">
    <?php $this->renderPartial('advanced_search',array('model'=>$model)); ?>
</div>


<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped condensed hover',
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'selectableRows'=>1,
    'selectionChanged'=>
        'function(id){ location.href = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);}',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'username',
        'email',
        'fname',
        'lname',
        array(
            'name'  => 'combineRoles',
            'value' => '($data->getCombineRoles())',
            'header'=> CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('combineRoles')),
            //'filter'=> CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'combineRoles'),
        ),
    )));
?>
```

my advanced_search.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this UserController */
/* @var $model User */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="wide form">
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
        'method' => 'get',
    )); ?>

        <?php

            $dataRole = array('Project Mentor', 'Personal Mentor', 'Domain Mentor', 'Mentee');
            $dataRoleVal = array(0,1,2,3);
            echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'firstField', array_combine($dataRoleVal, $dataRole),
                array('style' => ''));

            echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'criteria', array('Exactly', 'Greater Than',
                    'Less Than'), array('style' => ''));

            echo $form->textField($model, 'quantity', array('hint'=>'', 'style' => ''));

            $data = array('Enabled', 'Disabled');
            $data1 = array(0,1);
            echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'disable', array_combine($data1, $data), array('style' => ''));

        ?>

        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search', array("class" => "btn btn-primary")); ?>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
    <!-- search-form -->
</div>
```

my UserController.php

```
public function actionAdmin()
{

    echo("<script>console.log('actionAdmin');</script>");


    $model=new User('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['User'])){
        $model->attributes=$_GET['User'];

    }

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Update: as requested here is my model User.php

```
    <?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'user':
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $fname
 * @property string $mname
 * @property string $lname
 * @property string $pic_url
 * @property integer $activated
 * @property string $activation_chain
 * @property integer $disable
 * @property string $biography
 * @property string $linkedin_id
 * @property string $fiucs_id
 * @property string $google_id
 * @property integer $isAdmin
 * @property integer $isProMentor
 * @property integer $isPerMentor
 * @property integer $isDomMentor
 * @property integer $isStudent
 * @property integer $isMentee
 * @property integer $isJudge
 * @property integer $isEmployer
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Administrator $administrator
 * @property DomainMentor $domainMentor
 * @property Mentee $mentee
 * @property Message[] $messages
 * @property Message[] $messages1
 * @property PersonalMentor $personalMentor
 * @property ProjectMentor $projectMentor
 * @property Ticket[] $tickets
 * @property Ticket[] $tickets1
 * @property Domain[] $domains
 */
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $password2;
    public $vjf_role;
    public $men_role;
    public $rmj_role;
    /* advanced search variables */
    public $firstField;
    public $quantity;
    public $criteria;
    /*assign variables */
    public $userDomain;
    public $userId;
    /*temporary variables currently not stored in db*/
    public $employer;
    public $position;
    public $start_year;
    public $degree;
    public $field_of_study;
    public $school;
    public $graduation_year;
    public $combineRoles;
    /*Change the value when the system is deploy */
    public static $admin = 5;
    /* The most expert in the Domain */
    public static $condition = 8;

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return User the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('username, password, password2, email, fname, lname', 'required'),
            array('activated, disable, isAdmin, isProMentor, isPerMentor, isDomMentor, isStudent, isMentee, isJudge, isEmployer', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('username, fname, mname, activation_chain, linkedin_id, fiucs_id, google_id', 'length', 'max' => 45),
            array('password, email, pic_url', 'length', 'max' => 255),
            array('lname', 'length', 'max' => 100),
            array('biography', 'length', 'max' => 500),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, username, password, email, fname, mname, lname, pic_url, activated, activation_chain, disable, biography, linkedin_id, fiucs_id, google_id, isAdmin, isProMentor, isPerMentor, isDomMentor, isStudent, isMentee, isJudge, isEmployer', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }


    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
        return $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $this->password);
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'administrator' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Administrator', 'user_id'),
            'domainMentor' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'DomainMentor', 'user_id'),
            'mentee' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Mentee', 'user_id'),
            'messages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Message', 'receiver'),
            'messages1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Message', 'sender'),
            'personalMentor' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'PersonalMentor', 'user_id'),
            'projectMentor' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'ProjectMentor', 'user_id'),
            'tickets' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Ticket', 'assign_user_id'),
            'tickets1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Ticket', 'creator_user_id'),
            'domains' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Domain', 'user_domain(user_id, domain_id)'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'User ID',
            'username' => 'User Name',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'password2' => 'Re-type Password',
            'email' => 'e-mail',
            'fname' => 'First Name',
            'mname' => 'Middle Name',
            'lname' => 'Last Name',
            'pic_url' => 'Pic Url',
            'activated' => 'Activated',
            'activation_chain' => 'Activation Chain',
            'disable' => 'Disabled',
            'biography' => 'Biography',
            'linkedin_id' => 'Linkedin',
            'fiucs_id' => 'Fiucs',
            'google_id' => 'Google',
            'isAdmin' => 'Administrator',
            'isProMentor' => 'Project Mentor',
            'isPerMentor' => 'Personal Mentor',
            'isDomMentor' => 'Domain Mentor',
            'isStudent' => 'Student',
            'isMentee' => 'Mentee',
            'isJudge' => 'Judge',
            'isEmployer' => 'Employer',
            'vjf_role' => 'Virtual Job Fair Roles:',
            'men_role' => 'Mentoring Platform Roles:',
            'rmj_role' => 'Remote Mobil Judge Roles:',
            'employer' => 'Current Employer',
            'position' => 'Position',
            'start_year' => 'Start Year',
            'degree' => 'Highest Degree',
            'field_of_study' => 'Field of Study',
            'school' => 'University',
            'graduation_year' => 'Graduation Year',
            'rmj_role' => 'Remote Mobil Judge Roles:',
            'firstField' => 'Type: ',
            'criteria' => 'Assigned to: ',
            'quantity' => 'projects, mentors, or mentees',
            'combineRoles' => 'Roles',

        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.


        if ($this->firstField === 0) {
            $this->isProMentor = 1;
        } else if ($this->firstField === 1) {
            $this->isPerMentor = 1;
        } else if ($this->firstField === 2) {
            $this->isDomMentor = 1;
        } else if ($this->firstField === 3) {
            $this->isMentee = 1;
        }

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;


        //$criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
        $criteria->compare('username', $this->username, true);
        //$criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('email', $this->email, true);
        $criteria->compare('fname', $this->fname, true);
        //$criteria->compare('mname', $this->mname, true);
        $criteria->compare('lname', $this->lname, true);
        //$criteria->compare('pic_url',$this->pic_url,true);
        $criteria->compare('activated', $this->activated);
        //$criteria->compare('activation_chain',$this->activation_chain,true);
        $criteria->compare('disable', $this->disable);
        //$criteria->compare('biography',$this->biography,true);
        //$criteria->compare('linkedin_id',$this->linkedin_id,true);
        //$criteria->compare('fiucs_id',$this->fiucs_id,true);
        //$criteria->compare('google_id',$this->google_id,true);
        //$criteria->compare('isAdmin', $this->isAdmin);
        $criteria->compare('isProMentor', $this->isProMentor);
        $criteria->compare('isPerMentor', $this->isPerMentor);
        $criteria->compare('isDomMentor', $this->isDomMentor);
        $criteria->compare('isStudent', $this->isStudent);
        $criteria->compare('isMentee', $this->isMentee);
        //$criteria->compare('isJudge', $this->isJudge);
        //$criteria->compare('isEmployer', $this->isEmployer);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }

    public function getCombineRoles(){
        $st = '';

        if ($this->isProMentor)
            $st .= 'Project ';
        if ($this->isPerMentor)
            $st .= 'Personal ';
        if ($this->isDomMentor)
            $st .= 'Domain ';
        if ($this->isMentee)
            $st .= 'Mentee';

        return $st;
    }

    /* retrieve all user ids in the system */
    public static function getAllUserId()
    {
        $userid = User::model()->findBySql("SELECT id from user, user_domain WHERE  ");
        return $userid;
    }


    public static function getCurrentUser()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        return $user;
    }


    public static function getCurrentUserId()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
    $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
    if ($user == null) { Yii::app()->getController()->redirect('/coplat/index.php/site/login');  }
        return $user->id;
    }


    public static function getUser($userid)
    {
        $user = User::model()->findByPk($userid);
        return $user;
    }

    public static function getUserName($userid)
    {
        $user = User::model()->findByPk($userid);
        return $user->username;
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->isAdmin;
    }

    public function isProMentor()
    {
        return $this->isProMentor;
    }

    public function isPerMentor()
    {
        return $this->isPerMentor;
    }

    public function isDomMentor()
    {
        return $this->isDomMentor;
    }

    public function isMentee()
    {
        return $this->isMentee;
    }

    public function isJudge()
    {
        return $this->isJudge;
    }

    public function isEmployer()
    {
        return $this->isEmployer;
    }

    public function isStudent()
    {
        return $this->isStudent;
    }

    public static function isCurrentUserAdmin()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        if ($user == null)
            return false;
        return $user->isAdmin;
    }

    public static function isCurrentUserMentee()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        if ($user == null)
            return false;
        return $user->isMentee;
    }

    public static function isCurrentUserProMentor()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        if ($user == null)
            return false;
        return $user->isProMentor;
    }

    public static function isCurrentUserDomMentor()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        if ($user == null)
            return false;
        return $user->isDomMentor;
    }

    public static function isCurrentUserPerMentor()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        if ($user == null)
            return false;
        return $user->isPerMentor;
    }

    public static function isCurrentUserJudge()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        if ($user == null)
            return false;
        return $user->isJudge;
    }

    public static function isCurrentUserEmployer()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        if ($user == null)
            return false;
        return $user->isEmployer;
    }

    public static function isCurrentUserStudent()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
        $user = User::model()->find("username=:username", array(':username' => $username));
        if ($user == null)
            return false;
        return $user->isStudent;
    }
```

Comment: Paste your model file(protected/models/User.php) code `public function search(){}`

Comment: @Athipatla thanks for taking a look. i updated post to show search func.

Answer (score -1):

OK I do not know what kind logic you were trying. I guess you want to list the data based on search criteria given in advanced_search.php. You need to write the logic for results in Search function.

If you are unable to understand let me know. Also activated, disable, isProMentor etc are individual fields? Or paste your entire model User.php here

```
$criteria->compare('activated', $this->activated);   
    $criteria->compare('disable', $this->disable);
    $criteria->compare('isProMentor', $this->isProMentor);
    $criteria->compare('isPerMentor', $this->isPerMentor);
    $criteria->compare('isDomMentor', $this->isDomMentor);
    $criteria->compare('isStudent', $this->isStudent);
    $criteria->compare('isMentee', $this->isMentee);
```

Comment: i think i understand. i added my logic to search() method but i can't seem to get it to do anything when submit occurs. activated, disable and all those listed there are individual fields. if by fields you mean columns in the db yes. i didn't create the database so thats just something i have to work with.

Comment: also ill include entire model for user so u can see what i've done.

Comment: on second look what exactly is this capturing from? would i need to name my drop down something?
$countryVal=Yii::app()->session['admincntry'];

Comment: still stuck on this any feedback?

Comment: Hi jsan, sorry for the late reply. I have given example in the above. I am retrieving the country of a logged in user from session with this Yii::app()->session['admincntry'];. Why do you use 'Project Mentor', 'Personal Mentor', 'Domain Mentor', 'Mentee' as separate fields is intentionally done or requirement. are you not getting the submitted data in the search function?

Comment: Sorry pressed send by accident. No I'm not getting it in my search function. I need seperate fields because my hope is to provide an advanced search and the way the database was designed each of those is a 0 or 1 . So isProjectMentor . I would've just done one column name roles and assigned 0,1,2 etc. I'm trying to do an advanced search where I let them select which role they want to perform the search on

Comment: For the session... Where would I place the name 'admincntry' could u paste view for the code that works with your search func

Comment: are you getting the submitted data in the search function? Do not confuse with the example given as I gave because you have requested where to add search logic. What is the error you are getting exactly?

Comment: i am not getting the submitted data in the search function. thats the problem I'm having. i don know where to find that submitted data. I'm not getting an error its just not doing what i need it to do.

Comment: could please paste the exact error? Also try to print the array in the search function after submission.